# Does fread ignore ascii text?

Tags: c, binary, fread

I have searching arround and I couldn't find an answer...
Does the fread() in C ignore the ascii text on a file?
For exemple, if I get a file like this:

```
this is ascii
16
words
words
and then binary
1E 04 1A 00 07 FF
```

So, there is anyway for I get only the binary in the end of the file and skip the ascii code? or fread just ignores it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That file appears to contain nothing but ASCII. The last line just happens to consist of hexadecimal digits and spaces. If you meant that the line "and then binary" is followed by a 6-byte sequence whose hexadecimal representation is `1E 04 1A 00 07 FF`, please update your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking if `fread()` skips information automatically, no. The `fread()` function will read from the *current* file position for as many bytes as you tell it to. It will *not* skip ASCII or textual or any other sort of information.

If you're only getting the binary stuff then that's where the file position was pointing to when you tried to read it.

If you only *want* to read the "binary" (quoted since, even though it's hex digits, that's *still* ASCII) stuff at the end, you will have to detect it somehow and skip it yourself until you reach that point.

For example, if it's always at offset 42 in the file, you can use `fseek` to go to that point. If it's always on the sixth line, you can read characters until you reach the fifth newline.

The method you choose will depend on the data layout and *how* you can detect the start of the binary information.

Comment: So, if I open a file for binary reading, the pointer will start at the first binary ignoring the portion of ascii code in the beginning?

Comment: @JoãoSilva: no. Opening for binary will simply disable translations that may be allowed in text mode (such as CR/LF to NL translation or, shudder, stripping trailing spaces when reading from a FB80 data set on the mainframe). It doesn't _skip_ anything.

Comment: I guess that you edited your answer. In my test files I will knew allways where the binary begins, since I know it I have to use fseek to move the pointer to the start of binary and then start reading, is that what I have to do?

Comment: @JoãoSilva: yes, I added that since I realised your question may be one of two _different_ things: "why is my fread skipping" or "how do I get fread to skip". As you suggest, you can `fseek` to where the binary begins, then start reading from there, `fread` won't do the seeking for you.